# IBM RAD With Java 1.5 wont compile code with generics

Tags: java, generics, compiler-errors, ibm-rad

I have some code that has generic references in it and my IBM RAD IDE will not compile the code, instead treating it as an error.  I have checked the version of the JRE its pointing to across all the Enterprise Project's and it is 1.5 which I am told does support generics.  Also I checked that all the libraries for WAS were pointing to the correct version and that the Compiler Compliance Level was set correctly (which it was at 5.0 and i changed it to 6.0 with no luck either)

@@EDIT - to answer the question of the comment below I am using RAD version 7.0.0.10 and yes I checked the compiler properties of the entire IDE as well as the individual project that was having issues - tried pointing both of these to a local jre6 and still cannot get it to compile.

@@EDIT - I did not mention that I did also check the version of the JDK and the JRE and they are both 1.5 - the JDK i am using for the project and the IDE are as follows:  C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP70\jdk\bin\java.exe and C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP70\jdk\jre\bin\java.exe  and again both are version 1.5

Does anyone have any suggestions as to anything else I can try?  I have issues like this with RAD all the time and I dont know about anyone else but they took eclipse and made it complicated and dysfunctional.

Comment: Which version of RAD are you using ? Did you check the project properties and not just the IDE properties ?

Comment: I am using RAD version 7.0.0.10 and yes I checked the compiler properties of the entire IDE as well as the individual project that was having issues - tried pointing both of these to a local jre6 and still cannot get it to compile.

Comment: It is showing up as not recognizing the generics in the source or just showing up in the problems pane after you run the compile?

RAD I have gotten familiar with quirky bugs, Sometimes closing the IDE and relaunching or closing and opening the project can sometimes correct the bug.

Comment: Can you post the errors you are getting ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the JRE System Library and the Websphere Application Server libraries had been pointing to the wrong place - they were marked as Websphere Portal 6.1 and not Websphere Application Server 6.1 - and who KNOWS what JRE/JDK configurations that package had - I am very very sorry for wasting everyone's time, this was something I did not even see until I scrolled to the right out of curiosity.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check the Java compiler settings in RAD.  This is separate from the JRE used, so even with a Java 6 runtime, the compiler may still be set to Java 1.4.

Comment: I did not mention that I did also check the version of the JDK and the JRE and they are both 1.5 - the JDK i am using for the project and the IDE are as follows:  C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP70\jdk\bin\java.exe and C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP70\jdk\jre\bin\java.exe  and again both are version 1.5

Comment: That doesn't matter.  The crucial question is what the internal compiler in RAD is set to.